# FORMAT issue while import CSV to ODI ? UTF8 without BOM?

Tags: oracle, csv, import

I have the next problem.
I have a csv file with many rows.
No matter what is the frist column or how many rows I have in the csv, when I import it into the table (via ODI), I will receive on the output:
[image]

So the problem is the string "ďťż". In the first column I have the number 53. Even if I move the first column or I have 10 rows the result is "ďťż" on the first column of the first row.

Thank you,

Comment: The letters `ďťż` correspond to the UTF-8 BOM (`EF BB BF`) when interpreted as Windows-1250 (the "Central European" code page in Windows). This indicates you are reading the file in your system's default code page because your have not specified the CSV file encoding in ODI. Other Unicode characters will also break.

Comment: And the solution? I know what you just told. Thanks!

Comment: The solution is to specify the file encoding? I thought that would be obvious.