# How to insert Japanese (double byte) characters from a flat file (.txt) in a table in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2012, oracle-data-integrator

I am using ODI to load data from .txt to a table in sql server. The file has the Japanese and Russian characters, but when ODI loads the data in the table it’s showing as “?????”.
Can anyone please help me here.
Thank you.

Comment: You must specify the file encoding in ODI.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48922670/format-issue-while-import-csv-to-odi-utf8-without-bom

Comment: How can I specify the file encoding in odi??

Comment: How to do that??